# Android: Custom bullets on seekbar progress

Tags: android, background, seekbar

I would like an opinion of how to create a custom seekbar like the one in the picture below.
I am interested in how to create those bullets on the seekbar (which should be dinamically placed depending of an array, ie. Say I have to put bullets on 10%, 27% and 60% of the progress).

[image]

Any ideas of how to create that?

Comment: This isn't something new, there are examples out there on how to do it. Do you want the seek to be fixed, only between those defined points?

Comment: No, the bullets should somehow be "over" the seekbar and do not change its progress. They'll only notify user that at that point in the seekbar there will be something of greater meaning.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following links were very helpful so I am sharing:
https://github.com/dolphinwang/RangeSeekbar 
https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.